# AJAX Can't be Executed in CodeIgniter Form Submission

Tags: php, ajax, json, forms, codeigniter

I'm new in AJAX programming and working on a project that should use AJAX.

I'm using PHP with CodeIgniter framework, and I want to create forms that when submitted, it will return a success message without reloading the page, that's why I chose ajax. But from the code that I have made, it works without reading the AJAX, it move to another page and of course, no success message to be displayed

So my main problem is my AJAX form submission can't be executed and I don't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my controller.php

```
public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('advice', 'Advice', 'required');
    $data["CatId"]=$this->viewbook_model->getCategory();
    $this->ckeditor->basePath = base_url().'assets/ckeditor/';
    $this->ckeditor->config['toolbar'] = array(
                    array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-','Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo','-','NumberedList','BulletedList' )
                                                        );
    $this->ckeditor->config['language'] = 'it';
    $this->ckeditor->config['width'] = '730px';
    $this->ckeditor->config['height'] = '300px';            

    //Add Ckfinder to Ckeditor
    $this->ckfinder->SetupCKEditor($this->ckeditor,'../../assets/ckfinder/'); 

    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $this->load->model('feedback_model');
    $data['feedback'] = $this->feedback_model->get_subject();

    $advice_list = $this->feedback_model->get_subject();
    $x = 0;
    foreach($advice_list AS $al)
    {
        $data['feedback'][$x] = array(
            'CategoryAdviceId' => $al['CategoryAdviceId'],
            'CategoryAdviceName' => $al['CategoryAdviceName']
        );
        $x++;
    }

    $data['booklist'] = $this->feedback_model->find($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $book_list = $this->feedback_model->find('username');
    $y = 0;
    foreach($book_list AS $bl)
    {
        $data['booklist'][$y] = array(
            'AssetTitle' => $bl['AssetTitle'],
            'bi' => $bl['bi']
        );
        $y++;
    }

    $data['adviceid'] = $this->feedback_model->get_adviceId();
    $adviceid_list = $this->feedback_model->get_adviceId();
    $x = 0;
    foreach($adviceid_list AS $adv)
    {
        $data['adviceid'][$x] = array(
            'AdviceId' => $adv['AdviceId']
        );
        $x++;
    }

    $page_content["page_title"] = "Send Feedback";
    $page_content["title"] = "Suggestion and Feedback";
    $page_content["icon_title"] = "home";

    $menu_params["current_navigable"] = "Feedback";
    $menu_params["sub_current_navigable"] = "";

    $page_content["menu"] = $this->load->view("main_menu", $menu_params, true);
    $page_content["content"] = $this->load->view("feedback", $data, true);
    $page_content["navmenu"] = $this->load->view("nav_menu", $data, true);

    $this->load->view("template/main_template", $page_content);
    }else{
        redirect('login/restricted');
    }
}
//this is the function that sent data to model and return json to view for display success message
function insert_to_db()
{
    $this->feedback_model->insert_into_db();

    echo json_encode('true');
}
```

this is my form code in view.php

```
<form id="feedback_form" name="feedback_form" action="<?php echo base_url();?>feedback/feedback/insert_to_db" method="post" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">

                 <div class="control-group">

                    <!--FEEDBACK TYPE-->

                        <label class="span2 control-label" >Feedback for</label>

                        <div class="controls with-tooltip"> 
                        <select  class="input-tooltip span5" tabindex="2" id="CategoryAdviceSelect" name="CategoryAdviceSelect" onchange="showhidebook();" >
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Your Feedback For..</option>
                         <?php 
                            for($x = 0 ; $x < count($feedback) ; $x++) 
                            { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $feedback[$x]['CategoryAdviceId']?>"><?php echo $feedback[$x]['CategoryAdviceName'] ?></option>
                            <?php 
                            } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>  
                </div>

            <!--SUBJECT-->  
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label">Subject</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="span5" maxlength="50" id="Subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Type Your Feedback Subject.."  />
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>                      
                </div>

            <div id="emptybox"></div>
            <!--CHOOSE BOOK-->  
            <div id="showupbox" style="display: none;">             
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Choose Book</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <select  class="chzn-select span5" tabindex="2" id="BookSelect" name="BookSelect">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Your Feedback For..</option>
                             <?php 
                                for($y = 0 ; $y < count($booklist) ; $y++) 
                                { ?> 
                                    <option value="<?php echo $booklist[$y]['bi']?> - <?php echo $booklist[$y]['AssetTitle']?>"><?php echo $booklist[$y]['AssetTitle']?></option>
                                <?php 
                                } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            <!--ADVICE-->   
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label" >Suggestion</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo $this->ckeditor->editor("Advice",""); ?>
                      </div>                        
                </div>

            <!--Type Advice ID-->
            <div class="control-group hidden">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label" >Sugg</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                    <?php 
                            for($x = 0 ; $x < count($adviceid) ; $x++) 
                            { ?> 
                        <input type="text" class="span5" maxlength="50" id="TypeAdviceId" name="TypeAdviceId" value="<?php echo $adviceid[$x]['AdviceId']?>"/>
                    <?php
                            } ?>
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="control-group hidden">
                    <label for="limiter" class="control-label" >Sugg</label>

                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" class="span5" maxlength="50" id="NoBook" name="NoBook" value="-"/>
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
            </div>  

                <!--div class="alert alert-success">  
                      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>  
                      <strong>Success!</strong> Thanks for your feedback!   
                    </div--> 

                <div class="bton1">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary round" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary round" type="refresh">Reset</button>
                    </div>
        </form>
```

this is my script and AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this is for CKEDITOR validation
    for(var name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances["Advice"].on("instanceReady", function() {
            // Set keyup event          
            this.document.on("keyup", updateValue);
            // Set paste event
            this.document.on("paste", updateValue);     
        }); 

        function updateValue() {
            CKEDITOR.instances["Advice"].updateElement(); 
            $('textarea').trigger('keyup');
        }
   } 
    //this is my form validation
    $("#feedback_form").validate({
     ignore: 'input:hidden:not(input:hidden.required)',
        rules: {
            CategoryAdviceSelect:"required",
            Subject:"required",
            Advice:"required",
            BookSelect:{
                    required: function(element){
                    return $("#CategoryAdviceSelect").val()==1;
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            CategoryAdviceSelect:"Please select one of category advice",
            Subject:"This field is required",
            Advice:"This field is required",
            BookSelect:"This field is required",
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              if ($(element).attr('name') == 'Advice') {
                  $('#cke_Advice').after(error);
              } else {
                  element.after(error);
              }
          },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().addClass("help-block");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass("help-block");
        }
    });
    //this is my ajax submission
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
     var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
     var methodtype = $(this).attr("method");
     $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: methodtype,
        data : {
            CategoryAdviceSelect:CategoryAdviceSelect,
            Subject:Subject,
            Advice:Advice,
            BookSelect:BookSelect,
            TypeAdviceId:TypeAdviceId,
            NoBook:NoBook
               },
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        success : function(data){
                setTimeout(function() {location.reload(true)}, 1700);
                $('#success .success-content span').html('Thankyou for your <b>feedback</b>');
                $('#success').fadeIn();
                setTimeout(fade_out, 1200);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `<?php echo base_url();?>feedback/feedback/insert_to_db` is this the correct url

Comment: I think so, because it's working properly without AJAX with that url @Nouphal.M

Comment: have you checked of any js errors. use firebug

Answer (score 0):

instead of form tag just use: (in codeigniter)

```
<?php $attr = array('id'=>'feedback_form', 'name'=>'feedback_form', 'class'='form-horizontal', 'novalidate'=>'novalidate');?>
<?php echo form_open('feedback/feedback/insert_to_db', $attr);?>
```

change in ajaxfunction (change button click event to form submit event)

```
$("#feedback_form").submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 var methodtype = $(this).attr("method");
 $.ajax({
    url : formURL,
    type: methodtype,
    data : {
        CategoryAdviceSelect:CategoryAdviceSelect,
        Subject:Subject,
        Advice:Advice,
        BookSelect:BookSelect,
        TypeAdviceId:TypeAdviceId,
        NoBook:NoBook
           },
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json'
    },
    success : function(data){
            setTimeout(function() {location.reload(true)}, 1700);
            $('#success .success-content span').html('Thankyou for your <b>feedback</b>');
            $('#success').fadeIn();
            setTimeout(fade_out, 1200);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```